# Error while deploying custom widget in VAADIN 6

Tags: java, jar, widget, vaadin

I created a custom VAADIN 6 widget. It worked fine. then i did the following

1. Create fresh VAADIN 6 project.
2. Add that jar to WEB-INF-> lib folder.
3. Add that jar to classpath.
4. inherit my custom widget in new projects widgetset file. like

`<inherits name="com.vaadin.signature.signaturepad.SignaturePadWidgetset" />`

5. In Web.xml i set widgetset.
6. Then i compile my widgetset.
7. This is the pattern i follow while creating the widget.
   [image]

Now when i add this component in my application class it throws an error.

```
Widgetset does not contain implementation for com.vaadin.signature.signaturepad.SignaturePad. Check its @ClientWidget mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions. Unrendered UIDL:
 -Unrendered UIDL
 -com.vaadin.signature.signaturepad.SignaturePad(NO CLIENT IMPLEMENTATION FOUND) id=PID2 clicks=0 message=Click here.
```

I created a jar file from my `SignatureComponent` package. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have to compile the widget set.  https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/addons.compiling.html

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that. after creating it i compiled my widgetset

Comment: And you specified in your web.xml to use your newly compiled widgetset? The new widgetset is also deployed in /VAADIN folder?